# Can't run Windows 7 after install

Tags: windows-7, windows, partitioning

When I installed Windows 7, I wanted to do a clean install. I deleted all the partitions, and created 1 new partition on it. Then I installed Windows. When the Windows installer is done, Windows reboots. A black screen pops up with the message: `Can't start Windows`.

1. Place the Windows install disk and reboot the computer.
2. Select the language and click Next.
3. Click on "restore computer".

I did that also, but I noticed that Windows is getting installed every time on the D: drive... The computer is loading C: and can't find some files. That's because everything is on D:.

Does anyone have a solution to change the install to the C: drive?

Comment: If its trying to boot to D then you have more then a single partition.  Why don't you let the Windows installer create the partitions it needs?

Comment: How do i do that?

Answer (score 0):

While making a clean install, when the disk option opens, go to advanced option and delete all partitions one by one. The create a new partition where Windows is to be installed. When you create the first partition, Windows automatically creates a sytem partition of 100 MB.